# Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2010

I am trying to create an excel sheet in which when I select a drop down list option an input box shows up and asks the user to enter a number. This is to create a "skill planner" for a game I play. So I am using the code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Range("A4")

Case "Endurance"
Call Module1.GetEndurance
Case "Active Regeneration"
Call Module2.GetActiveRegen

End Select

End Sub
```

in ThisWorkbook and inside Module1 is

```
Sub GetEndurance()
Dim QtyEntry As Integer
Dim MSG As String
Const MinSkill As Integer = 0
Const MaxSkill As Integer = 100
MSG = "Please enter skill level between " & MinSkill & " and " & MaxSkill
Do
    QtyEntry = InputBox(MSG)
    If IsNumeric(QtyEntry) Then
        If QtyEntry >= MinSkill And QtyEntry <= MaxSkill Then Exit Do
        End If
            MSG = "... Really? I told you the valid options..."
            MSG = MSG & vbNewLine
            MSG = MSG & "Please enter skill level between " & MinSkill & " and " & MaxSkill
            Loop
Sheet2.Range("B2").Value = QtyEntry

End Sub
```

Module2 has the exact same code except it's called `GetActiveRegen()` and it goes to `Sheet2.Range("B3").Value = QtyEntry`.

When I select one of these two drop down options that input box shows up and I can put in a number, it puts that number where it's suppose to, the problem I have is that it keeps asking me to put in a number, if I hit cancel I get the error 13 message, if I put in no answer and click ok then it gives me the error 13 message. This is my first time doing programming in excel VBA and I have no real programming experience so this is getting highly frustrating. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The error is showing on this line:

```
 QtyEntry = InputBox(MSG)
```

Comment: The error is showing on this line:

 QtyEntry = InputBox(MSG)

Comment: I think it keeps asking is because you are using `Workbook_SheetChange` event. Once you ask the user for input and put the value to the sheet it will trigger the same `Workbook_SheetChange` event

Comment: I see what you mean... maybe I can make the macro something that runs based on something else than the drop down list changing like a button or something. I'll try that here in a little.

Comment: I appreciate helping you and I will do that onwards. As the question "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch" has been answered please mark the answer as the solution and vote it up if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You've chosen the wrong datatype for QtyEntry in the declaration. Choose string instead of integer.

```
Sub GetEndurance()
Dim QtyEntry As String
Dim MSG As String
Const MinSkill As Integer = 0
Const MaxSkill As Integer = 100
MSG = "Please enter skill level between " & MinSkill & " and " & MaxSkill
Do
    QtyEntry = InputBox(MSG)
    If QtyEntry = "" Then Exit Do
    If IsNumeric(QtyEntry) Then
        If QtyEntry >= MinSkill And QtyEntry <= MaxSkill Then Exit Do
        End If
            MSG = "... Really? I told you the valid options..."
            MSG = MSG & vbNewLine
            MSG = MSG & "Please enter skill level between " & MinSkill & " and " & MaxSkill
            Loop
Sheet2.Range("B2").Value = QtyEntry

End Sub
```

Comment: The only problem I have now is that the macro keeps running. When I entered say 50 it took it, but then it popped up with the initial msg box again. If I hit cancel it gives me the backup message box. Exit starts the whole thing again. How do I stop that?